# How to create users using a csv file created with LibreOffice Spreadsheet?

Tags: command-line, users, csv

I am trying to create multiple users and a group all at once to help me learn linux, but im running into trouble. (Mainly I have no clue what i am doing.)

```
groupadd Avengers:  useradd Hulk:   useradd Captain:    useradd Ironman:    useradd Hawkeye:    useradd Widow:
```

that is the commands i put (each command is in its own block. When I run the csv file from the terminal, I get:

```
newusers: user ',useradd Captain' does not exist
newusers: line 1: can't create user
newusers: error detected, changes ignored
```

I honestly have no clue where to begin, I am just guessing. Thank you.

Comment: Read `man useradd`. Read `man adduser`. Consider the odds of success: just guessing: 0.00, reading `man` pages: more than 0.